# search tool - ugrep: simply command to search all subdirectories?

Tags: windows, file-search

Question:
How to tell **ugrep** to always search complete subfolder structure in general?
So instead of defining specific levels of subdirectories how do I simply command to search all subdirectories completely?

**-16** in this command of **ugrep** commandline tool means,   let it search through 15 subdirectory levels(in any direction).

ugrep -Q "D:\" -O png -s -i **-16**

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a huge part of the ugrep documentation actually.

ugrep has a switch **-r** for recursive folder search